# Given a self-adjoint operator $A$, how does one calculate $d\Gamma(A)$?

Tags: operators, second-quantization

Given a self-adjoint operator $A$, I am interested in calculating the generator of the second quantization operator $d\Gamma(A)$.

In particular, I am interested in the case where $A=x\partial_x-\partial_x^2$, which is known as the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck generator. A paper that I am reading suggests that $d\Gamma(A)=A$ in this case, and I don't understand this statement. [This](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970628) is the paper I am referring to.

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine that the paper in question is using a mild abuse of notation. In general, one has that
$$\mathrm d\Gamma(A) \phi_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes \phi_n = \big(A\phi_1\big) \otimes \phi_2 \otimes \ldots + \ldots + \phi_1 \otimes \phi_2 \otimes \ldots \otimes \big(A\phi_n\big)$$

Operating in the position basis and assuming that $A$ is a differential operator, the RHS of the above expression could be understood as a formal analogue of the product rule, in the sense that one could introduce the (abuse of) notation

$$A \big(\phi_1\otimes \phi_2\big) \rightsquigarrow \big(A\phi_1\big) \otimes \phi_2 + \phi_1 \otimes \big(A\phi_2\big)$$

Comment: So $d\Gamma(A)=A$ in the special case that we have only one function, and not a tensor product of multiple functions?

Comment: @RyanHendricks The restriction of $\mathrm d\Gamma(A)$ to the 1-particle subspace of the Fock space is simply $A$, yes.